# Emoji support reading from file in python?

Tags: python, emoji

my program prints random strings from a file to the terminal 
i want to add emoji support to that but i have no idea how. 
lets say i have this:

> \U0001F337\U0001F338\U0001F337\U0001F338

in my .txt file i want to read from, how do i convert this to chars?
or how do i add support for emojis eg() to the stings in printing?

"" output is "ðŸŒ·" in terminal

```
import random
file = open('strings.txt')
content = file.read()
split = content.split("[0]")

print(split[random.randint(0, len(split) - 1)])
```

[file content](https://pastebin.com/K49t73Mp)

Comment: Does your text file contain literal slash escape sequences or actual emojis?

Comment: you don't need to add support for emoji in python, you need your terminal supports emoji and if it does when you will send to terminal emoji chars it will show you emoji

Comment: it, reads, from, a file. print("\U0001F337") or print("") works fine, and they display in my terminal

Comment: Do you *need* escaped Unicode sequences in that file in the first place, or could you simply use plain emojis? Are they JSON-encoded, or Python escape sequences?

Comment: @deceze "" output is "ðŸŒ·" in terminal for plain emojis

Comment: So, the file contains actual plain emoji then? Then you just need to add `encoding='utf-8'` to `open()`?

Comment: @deceze thanks, that solved the problem